# Traceroute works but ping does not

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, ping, wsl2, traceroute

My immediate goal is to ping from a device on my LAN to a Ubuntu 22.04 on WSL2.

**Context**

I am learning to use ROS2.
It allows communication between instances on different machines through FastDDS.
Once it is setup it should be fairly convenient.
Since I don't know how to set it up in my environment I asked [FastDDS: demo_nodes_cpp between WSL2 and Raspberry Pi](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/105511/fastdds-demo-nodes-cpp-between-wsl2-and-raspberry-pi).
To summarize:
FastDDS did not work by default, so I started researching how to make it work.
The conversation linked above lead to me circumventing the default way of discovering other ROS2 instances and instead configuring a discovery server.
This works, but now I want to find a solution without using a WireGuard VPN.
I believe this to be possible with the correct settings.
I hope that this might also be a way to find out how to route multicast packages.

**Status Quo**

I have a RasPi running Ubuntu 22.04 connected via WiFi on the subnet `192.168.178.0/24` with IP address `192.168.178.21`.

My Windows 10 PC has the IP `192.168.178.51`.

The WSL2 exposes its adapter with the address `172.27.112.1` on subnet `172.27.112.0/20`. The Ubuntu 22.04 running on WSL2 has the address `172.127.124.243`.

At `192.168.178.1` runs my fritz.box router.
I have configured it to route `172.27.112.0/20` through gateway `192.168.178.51`.
Pinging from `192.168.178.21` to `172.27.112.1` works:

```
[192.168.178.21]$ ping 172.27.112.1
  PING 172.27.112.1 (172.27.112.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
  From 192.168.178.1 icmp_seq=1 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 192.168.178.51)
  64 bytes from 172.27.112.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=127 time=5.46 ms
  ...
```

However, pinging from `192.168.178.21` to `172.27.124.243` does not work:

```
[192.168.178.21]$ ping 172.27.124.243
  PING 172.27.124.243 (172.27.124.243) 56(84) bytes of data.
  From 192.168.178.1 icmp_seq=1 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 192.168.178.51)
  ^C
  --- 172.27.124.243 ping statistics ---
  5 packets transmitted, 0 received, +1 errors, 100% packet loss, time 4063ms
```

This confuses me, since traceroute from `192.168.178.21` to `172.27.124.243` works:

```
[192.168.178.21]$ traceroute 172.27.124.243
  traceroute to 172.27.124.243 (172.27.124.243), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
   1  DESKTOP-XXXXXXX.fritz.box (192.168.178.51)  1.925 ms * *
   2  172.27.124.243 (172.27.124.243)  3.348 ms  2.353 ms  3.321 ms
```

Even more so since I can ping from `192.168.178.51` to `172.27.124.243`:

```
[192.168.178.51]$ ping 172.27.124.243

  Pinging 172.27.124.243 with 32 bytes of data:
  Reply from 172.27.124.243: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
  ...
```

Also, the ping in the other direction from `172.27.124.243` to `192.168.178.21` works:

```
[172.27.124.243]$ ping 192.168.178.21
  PING 192.168.178.21 (192.168.178.21) 56(84) bytes of data.
  64 bytes from 192.168.178.21: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=98.6 ms
  64 bytes from 192.168.178.21: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=2.19 ms
```

I have read that traceroute does not ECHO responses on [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/862979/i-can-tracert-to-an-ip-address-but-not-ping-it) but but this still leaves me clueless.

Edit: Firewall on `172.27.124.243`:

```
[172.27.124.243]$ sudo iptables -L
  [sudo] password for user:
  Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
  target     prot opt source               destination
  ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp   echo-request

  Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
  target     prot opt source               destination

  Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
  target     prot opt source               destination
```

On Windows, I have configured the firewall to allow all incoming ICMPv4 packages.
Although this should not impact ping on other machines.
I have also set `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\IPEnableRouter` to 1.

**Questions**

1. Why does traceroute 'work' but ping not?
2. How can I fix this?
3. What do I need to change in my configuration to make discovery (FastDDS) work with multicast on my network?

Comment: Your firewall perhaps blocks a ping request ICMP "echo reply" packet, but allows tracert ICMP "time exceeded" packet. Test by disabling temporarily the firewall on the receiving side.

Comment: @harrymc
I have added the firewall settings on `172.27.124.243` to my original post.

Comment: Please [Edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1817864/edit) your post with information. Comments like this are not readable.